# What are the roots of $\cos 2x−\sin x$ within $[0,2π]$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm unsure about how to solve this question, I've searched for a solution to a similar question but haven't found one and I've found the solution provided confusing to follow. If someone could explain to me how to solve this it would be a great help!

> What are the roots of $\cos2x-\sin x$ within $[0,2\pi]$?
>   [Here's a screenshot of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyc61.png)

Comment: Just expand $\cos(2x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- $$\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^2(x)$$
- Solving a quadratic equation might help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that as we can write $\cos 2x =1-2\sin^2 x$, the equation becomes, $$1-2\sin^2 x -\sin x =0 \implies (\sin x +1)(-2\sin x+1)=0$$
$$\implies \sin x =-1 \, \text{ and } \sin x =\frac12$$

How many values of $x$ satisfy the two conditions?

Answer (score 1):

The "screenshot" solution linked to by the OP *is* a little confusing. Maybe this'll help clarify things.

First of all, the trig identity $\sin\theta=\cos\left({\pi\over2}-\theta\right)$ allows us to replace the equation $\cos2x=\sin x$ with

$$\cos2x=\cos\left({\pi\over2}-x\right)$$

Next, we have the general fact for the cosine function that

$$\cos A=\cos B\iff A=2\pi k\pm B\quad\text{for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

This tells us

$$\cos2x=\cos\left({\pi\over2}-x\right)\iff2x=2\pi k\pm\left({\pi\over2}-x\right)$$

The $\pm$ sign tells us there are two cases: either $2x=2\pi k+{\pi\over2}-x$ or $2x=2\pi k-{\pi\over2}+x$. The first case gives us $3x=2\pi k+{\pi\over2}$, or

$$x={(4k+1)\pi\over6}$$

while the second case gives us

$$x={(4k-1)\pi\over2}$$

Finally, the constraint that we only want roots in $[0,2\pi]$ limits $k$ in the first case to $k=0,1,2$, and in the second case to $k=1$.  We find the roots

$$x={\pi\over6},{5\pi\over6},\text{ and }{9\pi\over6}$$

from the first case, and

$$x={3\pi\over2}$$

from the second case.  Observe, though, that ${9\over6}={3\over2}$, so we really only have three distinct roots:

$$x={\pi\over6},{5\pi\over6},\text{ and }{3\pi\over2}$$

If you're wondering why we got one root twice, it's because the curves $y=\cos2x$ and $y=\sin x$ are *tangent* at $x={3\pi\over2}$, so it has a multiple root there, in much the same way that polynomials can have multiple roots.

Remark:  For this particular problem, the trig identity $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$ is arguably a simpler way to get the roots, as other answers indicate.  Note, however, that this answer's approach works equally well for an equation like $\cos7x=\sin x$. It's always well worth having more than one arrow in your quiver.